# Program that outputs the lower right triangle with the input dimensions

Tags: java

the code I have so far allows for a right side triangle to be drawn but when the user inputs a higher dimension, the triangle no longer follows that pattern.

```
 for (int x=0; x<=n; x++){
             for (int i=3; i>=x; i--){
                 System.out.print(" ");
             }
             for (int y=1; y<=x; y++){
                 System.out.print("*");
             }
             System.out.println(" ");
         }
 System.out.println("\n4)\n");
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: what can i change so that it allows higher dimensions to follow that right side triangle ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int x=0; x<=n; x++){
    for (int i=0; i<n-x; i++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int y=1; y<=x; y++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("\n4)\n");
```

Here is is with litle modification.